# Resource Filtering with own plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-resources-plugin

Currently i develop my own plugin which will do resource filtering with loading of a an other file which influence the resource filtering.

I have the following code in my plugin (execute) method:

```
public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(encoding) && isFilteringEnabled(getResources())) {
        getLog().warn(
                "File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding "
                        + ReaderFactory.FILE_ENCODING
                        + ", i.e. build is platform dependent!");
    }
    Scope scope = convertToScope(getScope());
    getLog().info("Hallo welt. (" + scope + ")");

    if (getResources() != null) {
        for (Resource item : getResources()) {
            getLog().info(" --| Resource: " + item.getFiltering() + "|" + item.getDirectory());
        }
    }

    try {

        MavenResourcesExecution mavenResourcesExecution = new MavenResourcesExecution(
                resources, outputDirectory, project, encoding, null,
                nonFilteredFileExtensions, mavenSession);

        ValueSource valueSource = new ValueSource() {

            @Override
            public Object getValue(String expression) {
                getLog().info("Expression: " + expression);

                return "XXX";
            }

            @Override
            public List getFeedback() {
                getLog().info("getFeedback()");
                return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
            }

            @Override
            public void clearFeedback() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                getLog().info("clearFeedback()");

            }
        };
        mavenResourcesExecution.addFilerWrapperWithEscaping(valueSource,
                "\\@", "\\@", "@", false);

        mavenResourcesExecution.setUseDefaultFilterWrappers(false);

        mavenResourcesFiltering.filterResources(mavenResourcesExecution);

    } catch (MavenFilteringException e) {
        throw new MojoExecutionException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }

}
```

But during my integration tests the filtering will not be done. In my output i can't find the output of getValue(), getFeedback() etc.

Currently the output during my integration test looks like:

```
[INFO] Hallo welt. ()
[INFO]  --| Resource: true|src/main/resource-files
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[DEBUG] resource with targetPath null
directory src/main/resource-files
excludes []
includes []
[DEBUG] ignoreDelta true
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[DEBUG] file thisIsTheFirst.properties has a filtered file extension
[DEBUG] filtering ..it\configurationTest\src\main\resource-files\thisIsTheFirst.properties to ...\it\configurationTest\target\classes\thisIsTheFirst.properties
```

But unfortunately the getValue() method is not called in this case.

So the question is: Does someone has an idea what i'm doing wrong ? (Full source is available [here](https://gist.github.com/4124126).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is NOT to use regular expressions:

```
mavenResourcesExecution.addFilerWrapperWithEscaping(valueSource, "@", "@", "@", false);
```